# Can I use GNU GPL v3 in my free Android app?

Tags: gpl-3, license-compatibility

I have created an Android app implementing webview. In the webview, it is loading HTML files from the assets folder. The HTML files (and also associated javascript and css files) are GNU GPL v3 licensed and they are publicly available on GitHub. I have done that because the service should be available on PCs too, as a website.

To my knowledge, the Majority of Android libraries are Apache 2.0 licensed. Both of the licenses are incompatible with each other in my understanding. But since they function as separate entities, is it ok to use GNU GPL as the license or my Android app?

Also, I would like to mention that there is an occurrence where the app retrieves the value of an input field from webview. Does this affect them being called 'independent'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apache 2.0 license is incompatible with the GPL version 2, but it is compatible with the GPL version 3, according to [an article from GNU on compatible licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#apache2). So you can combine the Apache 2.0 code with the GPL version 3 code, as long as you license your project under the GPL version 3.